# Is developer preview of android L just a system image?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, googleio

How does android sdk and google provide developer preview? (like Android L developer preview). Is it just a system image or complete android environment.

Answer (score 1):

It is a system image as per the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a full android version, which is still in preview version, so it has bugs.
Google released a partial source for this version.

Answer (score 0):

In short Android L is not just a System image.

With every new android version release Google releases a whole lot if new features for both users and developers. All major releases come with their own APIs.

For example if you want to see the list of changes in KitKat (API 19) see

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html

Android L is still work in progress but it seems that much can be expected from it.

Comment: The update document is different, it specifies the list of changes as u mentioned, my guess is system image has the feel of new UI but my question is does it have the new widgets and new features also ?

Comment: yes... I didn't noticed that your were talking just about the Developer Preview.

Answer (score 0):

The Android L preview image can be flashed onto a Nexus 5 / Nexus 7 device .

The steps here are fairly simple to follow : 
https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html

Please note , if using Nexus 7 , it should be a Nexus 7 (2013 )version ( device product flo ) not the earlier one ( device product grouper ). Once installed on a device ,it will give you a good idea of what Android L has to offer.

In addition to that , update the SDK to  the latest through the SDK manager . There are examples in the SDK to start off Android L development with .